# PowerShell: create a new Active Directory user with password as a secure string

Tags: powershell

Having some trouble creating a command to create a new user in PowerShell, the code I'm using is:

```
PS C:\Users\Nicky> New-ADUser -Name johnd -GivenName John -Surname Doe -DisplayName John Doe $secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "pa$$word1" -AsPlainText -Force -AccountPassword $secpasswd
```

I can get it working without the `AccountPassword`, so I think the issue is when converting it to a secure string so the `-AccountPassword` will accept it.

Anyone any ideas on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax is wrong. Take a look at [New-ADuser](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617253.aspx) help page from Microsoft and this [one](http://ss64.com/ps/new-aduser.html) from SS64. Also if you have spaces in your string (example: `John Doe`) you should single quote it.

It should have a syntax similar to this:

`New-ADUser [-Name] <string> [-AccountExpirationDate <System.Nullable[System.DateTime]>]`...

You might want to do this instead:

```
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "pa$$word1" -AsPlainText -Force
New-ADuser -Name 'johnd' -GivenName'John' -Surname 'Doe' -DisplayName 'John Doe' -AccountPassword $secpasswd
```

Comment: Another possible solution would be to either put the whole `ConvertTo-SecureString` bit into parenthesis or use `$(ConvertTo-SecureString ...)` which would mean its first evaluated and the output is taken instead of relying on the fact that parenthesis are usually evaluated first. That said it's a better idea to have separate line for readability.